# Example of $a_k$ such that $\sum a_k$ doesn't converge but $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1, x< 1} \sum a_k x^k$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

In class we were taught that if $\sum a_k$ converges, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1, x < 1} \sum a_k x^k$ exists. The proof is based on the Cauchy's convergence criterion:
if the sum converges, then $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq 1$.

Is there an example of $a_k$ such that the limit exists but the sum doesn't converge, i.e. is there a counter example to the opposite statement?

Comment: You should read about Abel's theorem and Tauberian theorems.

Answer (score 1):

If you have non negative terms, the reciprocal is true. Indeed, the divergence of $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} a_n$ means that for all constant $C$, there exists a rank $N$ such that $\sum_{n = 0}^N a_n \geqslant C$ (we have divergence toward infinity). In this case, and if we assume that the radius of convergence of $(a_n)$ is $1$, set $f : x \mapsto \sum_{n \geqslant 0} a_nx^n$ defined for $-1 < x < 1$.

Clearly, $f$ is non negative and increasing on $[0,1]$ by non negativity of the $(a_n)$. Let $C$ be an arbitrarily large number. Then, for $N$ large enough, $\sum_{n = 0}^N a_n \geqslant 2C$ and for $x_0 < 1$ closed enough to $1$, we have $x_0^N \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$. We deduce that for all $x_0 \leqslant x < 1$,
$$
f(x) \geqslant f(x_0) \geqslant \sum_{n = 0}^N a_nx_0^n \geqslant \sum_{n = 0}^N a_nx_0^N \geqslant 2C \cdot \frac{1}{2} = C.
$$
It proves that $f(x) \rightarrow +\infty$ when $x \rightarrow 1^-$.

However, without the non negativity condition, we may find counterexamples, where the series of the $(a_n)$ diverges but remains bounded. For example, set $a_n = e^{i\theta n}$ for some $\theta \not\equiv 0\ [2\pi]$. As $a_n \not\rightarrow 0$, its series diverges (but remains bounded !), and for all $-1 < x < 1$, $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} a_nx^n = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} (e^{i\theta}x)^n = \frac{1}{1 - e^{i\theta}x} \rightarrow \frac{1}{1 - e^{i\theta}}$ when $x \rightarrow 1^-$. This limit exists because $e^{i\theta} \neq 1$.

In particular, for $\theta = \pi$, you obtain the real valued sequence $a_n = (-1)^n$ and the limit when $x \rightarrow 1^-$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_nz^n$ converges on the open unit disc and has a meromorphic continuation to an arc on the unit circle that includes a pole, then 
$\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$ converges nowhere on the unit circle. (I picked radius $1$  for simplicity; it works for a disc of convergence with any radius.) A *radial limit* from inside the open unit disc exists at any point on the unit circle to which the series has an analytic continuation. Your example of the geometric series $\sum z^n$ and a boundary point $e^{i\theta} \not= 1$ is a special case of this.